# How do I remove duplicates WITHIN a row using Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have data that looks like this:

| Wire | Point1 | Point2 | Point3 | Point4 | Point5 | Point6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | WP1 | WP1 | WP2 |  |  | WP2 |
| B | WP3 | WP4 | WP3 |  |  | WP4 |
| C | WP5 | WP5 | WP6 | WP7 | WP6 | WP7 |

(note the varying lengths of each row, and the duplicates)

I would like to have the end result be:

| Wire | Point1 | Point2 | Point3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | WP1 | WP2 |  |
| B | WP3 | WP4 |  |
| C | WP5 | WP6 | WP7 |

Duplicates removed, and blank spaces removed.

This would be VERY similar to the =UNIQUE() function, but that is not available in power query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Unpivot
- Group by Wire

  - Aggregate into sorted List of Unique Points
- Calculate Max number of items in all the Lists to use in the later Column Splitter
- Extract the List of points into semicolon separated string
- Split into new columns

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, Text.Type})),

//Unpivot
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Wire"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),

//Group by Wire
//Aggregate by sorted, unique list of Points for each Wire
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Wire"}, {
        {"Point", each List.Sort(List.Distinct([Value]))}}),

//Calculate the Max unique Points for any Wire (for subsequent splitting
maxPoints = List.Max(List.Transform(#"Grouped Rows"[Point], each List.Count(_))),

//Extract the List values into a semicolon separated list
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows", 
        {"Point", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),

//Then split into new columns using the semicolon delimiter
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Point", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv),maxPoints)
        
in 
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the commented steps of the M code were very helpful. I was able to get the exact output I wanted using your answer with slight modifications. (Removed the List.Sort() in the Group By Wire, skipped the maxPoints calculation)

Comment: @Ryouko Glad it's working for you. How are you determining the number of columns to split into for the final result?

Comment: I used the command:
`= Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "WPs", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"WPs.1", "WPs.2", "WPs.3", "WPs.4", "WPs.5", "WPs.6", "WPs.7", "WPs.8", "WPs.9", "WPs.10", "WPs.11", "WPs.12", "WPs.13", "WPs.14", "WPs.15", "WPs.16", "WPs.17", "WPs.18", "WPs.19"})`
And it filled any of the unused ending columns with null, which was fine for what I was doing.

Comment: @Ryouko That's OK when you don't mind the unused columns. BTW, Since the column you are splitting is named `WPs`, you can replace that long list of column names with merely: 19: `= Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "WPs", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv),19)`

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot easier to work with columns, so I'd recommend unpivoting the Point columns, removing duplicates, and then putting it into the shape you want.

Here's a full query you can past into your Advanced Editor to look at each step more closely:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUQoPMEQijYAkBIHYsTrRSk5gtjGYNIGzYWpMwGqcwWxTJNIMTJqjsGNjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Wire = _t, Point1 = _t, Point2 = _t, Point3 = _t, Point4 = _t, Point5 = _t, Point6 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Wire", type text}, {"Point1", type text}, {"Point2", type text}, {"Point3", type text}, {"Point4", type text}, {"Point5", type text}, {"Point6", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Wire"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each ([Value] <> "")),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows", {"Wire", "Value"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Wire"}, {{"Point", each Text.Combine([Value],","), type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Point", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Point1", "Point2", "Point3"})
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It was a little more difficult to follow than the other response.